# XPath - Get a list of nodes which has 3 children with specific tags

Tags: xpath

What is the xpath to use if I want to get the nodes that have a certain number of child nodes of a tag type?

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <p></p>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <p></p>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For example, in the markup above, I want to get `<tr>` tags that have 3 `<td>` children. The xpath should return the 1st and 3rd `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a condition based on the count statement, for example:

```
/table/tr[count(td)=3]
```

Comment: Nice! It is exactly what I was looking for.